# rake db:migrate conflicting with pre-loaded data on Heroku PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have an app on Heroku running on Postgres. The problem is: I needed to load some data on one of the tables, and I managed to do it using Heroku's `pg:push` command. The problem is that it only works after a `pg:reset`, which resets the database and pre-loads it's initial state, *then* I have to pre-load the data and *then* I must run the migrations. But the migrations won't work on this specific table, since it's already loaded with data.

So this is the situation I find myself in: my migrations fail because of this pre-loading, so I had to remove them - but I don't want to deal with these missing migrations everytime I must run them.

The question would be: is there any way to load data on Heroku's Postgres *after* the migrations have been executed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I tried to explain on my text: I used it, but it doesn't work if there's already data on the tables. And the pg:púsh doesn't work if the migrations have been already executed.

Comment: Welcome Rodrigues. You can write rake task to update existing data on the table. May be its helpful..